# How do I find my server's public key info to do certificate pinning in OkHttp?

Tags: https, okhttp

I have a server with a custom certificate on it issued by my own personal certificate authority. It's not on a public domain so it's not possible to use a standard certificate authority. I want to get an Android client to connect to this server using OkHttp. According to [the docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-certificate-pinner/), the code should look like this:

```
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add("myserver.com", "sha256/afwiKY3RxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig=")
    .build();
```

Where the SHA256 hash is, quoting [the docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-certificate-pinner/-builder/add/): "a hash of a certificate’s Subject Public Key Info, base64-encoded and prefixed with either sha256/ or sha1/". I have the cert and the key files for the server, but how can I get the required hash?

I'm using OkHttp 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a request to your server with the configuration above to see how that fails. The exception should tell you which pins were found.

You must do certificate pinning in coordination with your server team! Otherwise a change they make will prevent your client from being able to reach the server.

Comment: Unfortunately not. At least with this version of OkHttp, I just get a very uninformative `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` with no mention of any hashes.

Comment: Turn off certificate pinning and fix that underlying trust issue. Chances are your server’s root is not trusted by your device. (Is it a self-signed certificate?)